# No source code available for Scribe in GWT

Tags: java, xml, gwt, scribe

I'm getting this error trying to Compile my GWT Project:

```
No source code is available for type org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I have included the scribe .jar file in my "war/WEB-INF/lib", and imported it. Maybe I have to add it to the app_name.gwt.xml? I have tried to do it, but Scribe does not contains any .gwt.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Scribe with no problems. But it's a server-side library. You should have no references to it in your GWT  code.

Comment: That has been my solution. I've created a singleton in order to access to Scribe with client-server communication using servlets.

Answer (score 1):

In GWT you are restricted to use only some of the java classes since it is not possible to convert all the java classes to javascript. You can find a list of the allowed classes in this link: [List of Classes](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_util)

And it is not possible  use classes related to Threads,IO,Network, etc...because of the compatabilty.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the Java source code for Scribe in order for the GWT compiler to compile it (translate it into javascript). If it is available then you can add it to your source tree and and specify that it is "inherited" in the gwt.xml document.

Of course, check with Google's GWT forum for any updates. I know they are working on a better solution to this problem.

I just checked and Google has OAuth available as an extension to GWT. That is your best solution. Look here:

code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing OAuth1.0a, not OAuth2, and there's no compatibility. As I said, there's no .gwt.xml file in Scribe, so src attaching doesn't work.

Comment: No, the gwt.xml file is part of your GWT application, not Scribe. You need to add the source code to your source tree within your project and then make an entry to this file to let the GWT compiler know that this source code should be compiled (translated in javascript) by the GWT compiler.

Comment: Any library you want to use in GWT must have a `.gwt.xml` file, describing what packages can be compiled into JavaScript (among other things). If that file is not present, it is *possible* that you can make your own, but if the library uses classes that don't work in a browser (any file IO, most network, etc), this will not work.